# How to get answer from this Spark Scala program for Input : s= 'aaabbbccaabb' Output : 3a3b2c2a2b

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Scala program for
Input :

```
s= 'aaabbbccaabb'
```

Output :

```
3a3b2c2a2b
```

**find output by spark scala ?**

Comment: can you share at what step in the implementation are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `foldLeft` over the input string, with a state of `List[(Char, Int)]`. Note that if you use `Map[Char, Int]`, all occurrences of each character would be added up, weather they're beside each other or not.

```scala
s.foldLeft(List.empty[(Char, Int)]) {
  case (Nil, newChar) => (newChar, 1) :: Nil
  case (list@(headChar, headCount) :: tail, newChar) => 
    if (headChar == newChar) 
      (headChar, headCount + 1) :: tail
    else 
      (newChar, 1) :: list
}.map {
  case (char, count) => s"$count$char"
}
  .reverse // because we're prepending to the list, the reverse order of the iteration
  .mkString("")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val data = "aaabbbccaabb"
val fltlist = data.toList
          
val ans = fltlist.map((_,1)).foldRight(Nil: List[(Char,Int)])((x,y) => y match {
  case Nil => List(x)
  case ((c,i)::rest) => if (c == x._1)(c, i + 1):: rest else x::y
})

var i=0
while (i< (ans.length))
{
  print(ans(i)._2 + "" + ans(i)._1)
  i += 1
}
```

Comment: He's the OP, so I think he posted the solution that worked for him.